# Will this code work after maven build?

Tags: spring, maven, apache-poi

```
FileOutputStream something = new FileOutputStream(new File("blank"));
abc.write(output_file); 
something.close();
```

This is a part of a function that I will be calling this through http PUT at the controller.

Where will that "blank" file be saved? Any workaround?

Comment: Just add log `System.out.println(new File("blank").getAbsolutePath())`

Answer (score 1):

In the current directory.

Just like when you execute `less blank`or `notepad blank`, it shows you the blank file located in the current directory.

The current directory is the directory from which the `java` command running your program was executed.

You could have tested that by just executing your code, and looking for the file.

Comment: Have you read my answer? It answers your question. The file is saved in the current directory. The current directory is the directory from which the java command running your program was executed. So if you're in the directory `/home/tree` and are executing `java -jar myproject/target/myproject.jar`, the file will be created in `/home/tree`. Don't know how I could be clearer. Also re-read the comment you got from Andrzej, which is also crystal clear.